# Get or read version in asp.net for application deployed with octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm using TeamCity and Octopus Deploy to deploy an Asp.Net app

I want to show the version number that was used when the app was deployed

In teamcity I'm generating the version number using the vcs number

How can I read that info from asp.net or how can I save it for later retrieval?

Comment: I am sorry, but it was not clear to me from your question: the version of what are you trying to get? The version of Octupus? I got confused when you wrote: "How can I read that info from asp.net", are you referring to getting the Visual Studio version in which the application was written, or the target asp.net framework of your projects?

Comment: Octopus generate a nuget package with a number version, that number version can be created from distintct options. I want to read that version number to show inside my application

Comment: Octopus should follow the version number that is created in your build process. That way you can simply inspect your app's version. Octopus's nuget package than simply follows that version. At least that's how I got it working here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version is stamped onto your libraries (as long as you set the version number prior to building them).

This version number can be accessed at runtime:

```
string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

You can also [use the assembly version number in Octopus Deploy](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/09/sync-your-visual-studio-online-and-octopus-version-numbers/). This works with Team City, VSTS, and so on. This means the version displayed in Octopus, Team City, and the application itself will all match up and you'll avoid confusion.